# Windows Explorer integration of a shared OneDrive/Sharepoint folder without an account

Tags: windows-explorer, onedrive, shared-folders, sharepoint

With OneDrive/Sharepoint (please excuse my conflating of them), it is possible to create a shared folder, which can be set to "Anyone with the link can edit".
Thus, it is possible to share data and work on a common project with people outside one's organisation and people without a Microsoft365 account.

Is there a way for the latter group, i.e., the external people without a Microsoft365 account, to integrate this shared folder, to which they have access to, into their Windows Explorer?

Comment: In OneDrive you should be able to see folders shared with you, and that's an account level setting. If they have OneDrive running on their computer it'll show these shared folders there in the OneDrive subfolders. However, sharing as "anyone with a link can edit" is a significantly dangerous proposition. There are better ways to specify and control access that allows everyone who needs to edit, and prevents escaped links from ending up as major security issues for you.

Comment: @music2myear Sorry, I mistyped. The question is about people without a M365 account, so they will not have OneDrive running. I have fixed my question in that respect. Yeah, the "anyone with the link" option is not the safest one; but the issue is to get a convenient share, that integrates into Windows Explorer, for people who have no M365 account.

Comment: What about personal Microsoft accounts? You should be able to add external "contacts" in M365 for access. While web access is possible without the client, in order to integrate with Explorer I think it will require the local OneDrive client though.